# eclipse can't find compatible jre suddenly

Tags: java, eclipse

One day, it suddenly happened that eclipse can't compile the project. The eclipse can't find the compatible JRE for javaSE-1.7 anymore. I know that we can change the "JRE System Library" to one of my "Installed JREs" settings, but my project has too many child modules to change.

Reinstall JDK and Reconfig the "Installed JREs" did not help my "eclipse-jee-oxygen-1" recognize the compatible JRE again, even in a new blank workspace.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt eclipse oxygen runs without JDK 8

[Eclipse-oxygen-installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29)

```
eclipse.ini
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

Try adding -vm to eclipse.ini

```
-vm
[path-to-jdk-7-home]\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Comment: The vm param was tried as "jre/bin/server/jvm.dll" and "bin/javaw.exe", the problem is the same.

Comment: Have you tried for eclipse oxygen or older version? Oxygen release requires Java 8 to be run as per release document

Comment: I tried eclipse-jee-oxygen-3 which support jdk9, havn't tried older version.

Comment: I see that you have referred from JRE directory, could you please try pointing from JDK directory?

Comment: The jvm.dll is only contained in  the jre/bin/server folder in JDK directory.

Comment: Then sadly you could only use Eclipse Luna and Mars which supports JDK 7. There are significant changes from JDK 7 and JDK 8, please refer this link for supported JDK for each eclipse release. From eclipse neon, JDK 8 is supported.  [link] (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the windows env variable "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" whcich I setted to "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx4096m" cause the problem. When I remove it, then the eclipse start to recognize the compatible JRE again.